# What is the use of @All decorator in NestJS

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-swagger

What is the use of @All decorator in NestJS and does it handle all the requests that are not handled in other routes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@All()` is used for all supported HTTP Verbs. So `@All('/hello')` would essentially be `@Post('/hello')`, `@Put('/hello')`, `@Get('/hello')`, `@Delete('/hello')`, and `@Patch('/hello')`.

If you want a catch-all handler, you can use `@All('*')`, just make sure this is the last registered route handler as it will match **everything** and if it is registered too early then it will handle even your named routes

Comment: this is not working for me for just the root path with nestjs 9. `@All()` works for the root path, but it does not for `/id`. `@All('*/')` works for `/id`  but it does not for the controller root path... not a clue what's going on. Also having issues with POST